# Build constants in Visual Studio 2012 C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to write C++ application. How can I define `DEBUG` constant for `Debug` build configuration?

[image: build configuration constant visual studio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was looking on it all the time:

[image: Preprocesor definitions visual studio]

Visual Studio 2012 automatically defines `_DEBUG` for debug configuration, so it's possible to do:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
   ...
```

without changing any settings.